How to think about oxygen at a crystal site with formal charge 3+?
I am building a model of simple crystal lattices of rock salt type for different compounds. My goal is to make use of the measured values of ionization energies of atoms and formation energies of compounds from standard state elements and atomization energies of the elements to gain an understanding of the bond types.
The formal charges required for theoretical reasons are, in some cases, not the same as the charges of ions in reality. While looking at a table of Shannon radii, I noticed, it contains values for six-coordinated $\ce{N^5+}$, among other seemingly extreme charges. However, there is no six-coordinated $\ce{O^3+}$.

Is there really a compound, where nitrogen is six-coordinated 5+ cation? If not, how was this value calculated?
Can I reliably calculate crystal radii for any element in any formal oxidation state? I only need positive ions' radii.
Maybe I should, in case of $\ce{O^3+}$, try another approach and assign a minimum possible radius based on Pauling's first rule . For example: if the measured bond length is $\pu{209 pm}$, then the theoretical $\ce{O^3+}$ radius will be $$\frac{0.414}{1+0.414}\times\pu{209 pm} = \pu{61 pm}$$ for octahedral coordination. Is it safe to assume the real radius is less than that?


WRT Nitrogen https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5093683/ might be of interest. But I'm unsure if it is relevant.

@IanBush Ninjaed! Indeed hexafluoronitrates(V) are possible https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_pentafluoride

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022113999001396

https://www.ch.ic.ac.uk/rzepa/blog/?p=17858 https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acsomega.0c02969

Rzepa's blog I linked^ does have oxygen with formal charge 3+, but it's a theoretical hypercoordinated trication. Still, I think coordination of five is the main possibility for O with such high formal charge

@Mithoron I hope, you didn't misunderstand. Calculating radii from highly pressurized or charged molecules (that are already theoretical themselves) seems like a wild speculation. If you can do it, write an answer. In my model, the formal charge is not supposed to be for the ground state.

I'm really struggling to see what you are trying to do here; While I can just about see N5+ being part of a model to my mind O3+ just has no chemical relevance whatsoever. Maybe if you expand a bit on your model?

Note also ions are themselves just a model of NaCl and similar, yet another attempt to factorise the many body problem into a two body one, and in the strictest sense don't exist "in reality" in the lattice

@IanBush It is a convenient way for me to exclude structural components of materials incompatible with high-temperature superconductivity. Formally, I add electrons from "cations' " neutral free atoms to "anions' " until the outer shell electrons' average energies become equal.  These "anions" are not even bound states until lowered into their lattice positions: they are compressed collections of free electrons.  Whether the formal charges remain on the same sites or not becomes apparent once the calculation is finished.

Of the two species mentioned in the question, hexacoordinate nitrogen(V) (the Roman numeral V means oxidation state, not formal charge) is the better established case in prospective crystals. No compound having this nitrogen state is known experimentally, but theoretical calculations predict a nitrogen-pentafluoride salt containing $\ce{NF6^-}$ at high pressure[1]. The proposed hexacoordinate nitrogen(V) radius is likely based on this calculation.
Pentacoordinate nitrogen, in a lower oxidation state, has been experimentally obtained in an organic complex[2].
References

Kurzydłowski, D., Zaleski-Ejgierd, P. "Hexacoordinated nitrogen(V) stabilized by high pressure". Sci Rep 6, 36049 (2016). https://doi.org/10.1038/srep36049

Chenting Yan, ORCID logo a   Masato Takeshita,a   Jun-ya Nakatsuji,a   Akihiro Kurosaki, Kaoko Sato,Rong Shang, Masaaki Nakamoto Yohsuke Yamamoto, Yohei Adachi, Ko Furukawa, Ryohei Kishid and  Masayoshi Nakano. "Synthesis and properties of hypervalent electron-rich pentacoordinate nitrogen compounds". Chem. Sci., 2020, 11, 5082-5088. https://doi.org/10.1039/D0SC00002G.



Please review submitted edits carefully and do not approve the destructive and nonsensical ones.
